# How is buffer overflow handled while piping data to a QProcess's stdin?

Tags: qt, pipe

Our Qt application `write()`s huge amounts of data to a `QProcess`'s stdin.
Usually, the process reads faster than my Qt app's write rate. So things are fine.

The concern is what happens the other way round? Will the unread buffer keep increasing over time to a point beyond what an OS can permit? Or is there a limit set by Qt. I could not find anything in Qt's doc or I could not find any buffer overflow warning signal which I could have used to slow down the app's write rate.

Comment: It would depend on the OS and what underlying IPC mechanism is used. For Linux and pipes, `write` will block until data has been read of the pipe. See e.g. the [pipe manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

Comment: write() returns the number of actually written bytes, so if not all bytes could not be written to a buffer (system- or QProcess-level), the value will be lower than the length of your data. Thus one should always check the return value of write to not lose data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Qt's `QProcess::write()` is non-blocking and I assume Qt maintains the buffer before writing to system pipe.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld You are right - the return value needs to be checked. Also in addition to that, one also needs to check for the `bytesWritten()` signal since `write()` is non-blocking